# who belongs_to who - nested models - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, controller

Suppose I have a user table and a campaign table (with a user_id column) and that each campaign has one creator (who is a user), and a list of members, who are also (users). So I have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  has_many :campaigns
```

and

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController

  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :users 
  accept_nested_attributes_for :users
```

but I get an error : `ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method`belongs_to' for CampaignsController:Class)`

Comment: Those methods (`has_many`, `belongs_to`, `accepts_nested_attributes_for`) don't belong in your controllers. They belong in your models. I would recommend some Rails reading, such as: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the model relationship must be declared in your model file, not in your controller .
it should be :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns


class Campaign< ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :users 
  accept_nested_attributes_for :users
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods `#has_many` and `#belongs_to` are defined for ActiveRecord models, not ActionPack controller.

You need to create models (with migrations creating tables and columns): User and Camaign and define relationships there, and in controllers you just fetch models and show them on view, or update models with params from user.